# YouTube comment scraper not working/error?

Tags: web-scraping, youtube, youtube-data-api

I’m fairly new to coding/programming and I don’t know what I’m doing wrong here

I installed node.js and tried to run the following command:

youtube-comment-scraper -f json —outputFile C:\Users\P\Desktop\YTCS\Scrapes\file.json smn0HOvwoZ8

Cmd responses with „API response does not contain a „content_html“ field“
Node js responses with „Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier“

How can I get this to work?

Link to the scraper:
https://github.com/philbot9/youtube-comment-scraper

Comment: Does this relates to the fact that the app itself on the [official site](http://ytcomments.klostermann.ca/) stopped working?

Comment: No, this is completely independant to the site. https://github.com/philbot9/youtube-comment-scraper/issues/28

Comment: As the repository you shared is now deprecated, I would recommend you to have a look to [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) and specify `videoId` as a filter.